# Añadir botones con el método GRID

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo este programa :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("METODO GRILLA")

frame = Frame(root, bg='red',width=600, height=800)
frame.pack(
    expand=0,
    fill=tk.BOTH
)   
v = [
    "boton1",
    "boton2",
    "boton3",
    "boton4",
    "boton5",
    
]
for y in range(3):
    for add_scr in v:
        print("NOMBRE B O T T O O N ", add_scr)
        btn_scr = Button(
                frame,
                text=add_scr,
                width=10,
                height=4,
            )
        btn_scr.grid(row=len(add_scr), column=y, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Que apartir de una lista quiero añadir a un frame los botones, pero solo quiero que me añada 3 colunma y en otra fila el resto de botones, la salida que me sale ahora es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero algo como esto, donde me añado boton2, boton2, boton3 a la fila 1, y en la fila2 el resto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es posible hacerlo en un bucle??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sip, es posible!

#### Respuesta

Hice una función que hace lo que buscas:

```
import tkinter as tk

# esta función da el resultado redondeado hacia arriba de una división
def ceildiv(dividendo, divisor):
    # divmod nos devuelve una tupla con el cociente y el resto, desempaquetamos eso.
    cociente, resto = divmod(dividendo, divisor)

    # sumamos al cociente el resto convertido en booleano. Recuerda que True vale 1 y False 0.
    # Por lo que si hay resto se sumará 1.
    return cociente + bool(resto)

def grid_by_column(frame, columns, spacex=10, spacey=10):
    # obtenemos todos los widgets del frame
    widgets = frame.winfo_children()

    rows = ceildiv(len(widgets), columns)

    row = 0
    column = 0

    for widget in widgets:
        # ubicamos el widget en la esquina noroeste de la celda.
        widget.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="nw")

        # el siguiente widget será ubicado en la siguiente columna.
        column += 1

        # si alcanzamos la cantidad maxima de columnas...
        if(column >= columns):
            column = 0
        
            row += 1

    # le agregamos un espacio (en este caso a la derecha) a cada fila menos la ultima.
    # La ultima se omite para evitar que el frame tenga espacio vacío en el borde derecho.
    for row in range(rows-1):
        frame.rowconfigure(row, pad=spacex)

    # se hace lo mismo con las columnas. Se omite la ultima para evitar que haya espacio vacío en el borde inferior.
    for column in range(columns-1):
        frame.columnconfigure(column, pad=spacey)

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame()

for i in range(20):
    tk.Button(frame, text=i, width=2)

grid_by_column(frame, 3)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Esta función acepta 2 argumentos obligatorios, que son el Frame donde creaste los widgets y el numero de columnas maximo. También acepta dos opcionales que indica el espacio que debe haber entre widgets (spacex, spacey), que por default son 10.

Produce:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Bonus: Buenas practicas

En mi opinión, no vale la pena importar tkinter de dos formas diferentes. Además, hacer `from tkinter import *` no se considera buena practica, por que al hacer eso se crean MUCHAS variables globales en tu programa que podrías reemplazar sin querer por otra cosa. Por ejemplo imagina que tienes este código:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

Frame = "hola mundo"
Frame(root)
```

Te va a decir que Frame, que ahora es una cadena, no es llamable.

Esto se llama "contaminación del espacio de nombres".

Lo mejor en mi opinion es que te quedes con `import tkinter as tk` y que cada vez que uses algo de Tkinter le pongas el prefijo `tk.`.

Tu código modificado quedaría así (no incluye mi función):

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("METODO GRILLA")

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='red',width=600, height=800)
frame.pack(
    expand=0,
    fill=tk.BOTH
)   
v = [
    "boton1",
    "boton2",
    "boton3",
    "boton4",
    "boton5",
    
]
for y in range(3):
    for add_scr in v:
        print("NOMBRE B O T T O O N ", add_scr)
        btn_scr = tk.Button(
                frame,
                text=add_scr,
                width=10,
                height=4,
            )
        btn_scr.grid(row=len(add_scr), column=y, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Primero gracias por tu tiempo, segundo gracias por las buenas practicas siempre es bueno recordarlo, y por ultimo que maravilla de función, es que no se como se te ocurrió pero esta genial, muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada y gracias, me gustó escribirla c: